# Custom maximumBy and minimumBy in Haskell

Tags: haskell, reinventing-the-wheel

Going through the magnificent [Haskell Programming from first principles](http://haskellbook.com/), I'm currently reimplementing functions from standard libraries such as `maximumBy` and `minimumBy`.

Here are my current versions of them:

```
myMaximumBy :: (a -> a -> Ordering) -> [a] -> a
-- maximumBy in Data.List also throws an error on empty lists
myMaximumBy _ [] = error "empty list"
myMaximumBy f (x:xs) =
  foldr (\curMax x -> if f x curMax == GT then x else curMax) x xs

myMinimumBy :: (a -> a -> Ordering) -> [a] -> a
myMinimumBy f = myMaximumBy $ flip f
```

I know they're not total functions, but I'll get to rewriting them with something like `Maybe` later on.

I'm happy for any kind of feedback on how to make the code shorter, more readable, or more idiomatic.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73128/discussion-on-question-by-matthias-braun-custom-maximumby-and-minimumby-in-haske).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `maximumBy` folds a list of elements into a single element, it seems like a perfect candidate to use `foldr` or `foldr1`. However, we would need `a -> a -> a` instead of `a -> a -> Ordering`.

Let's have a look at `maximum` first, which can be defined via `max :: Ord a => a -> a -> a`:

```
maximum :: (Foldable t, Ord a) => t a -> a
maximum = foldr1 max
```

That looks simple enough to adapt to our `myMaximumBy`:

```
myMaximumBy :: (a -> a -> Ordering) -> [a] -> a
myMaximumBy f = foldr1 (maxBy f)
```

We now only need a `maxBy` that transforms an `a -> a -> Ordering` into a `a -> a -> a`:

```
maxBy :: (a -> a -> Ordering) -> a -> a -> a
maxBy comp x y = if x `comp` y == LT then y else x
```

Compared to your original solution, we now

- replaced explicit recursion by `foldr1`
- introduced a helper function that can get reused

Our new version is now easier to maintain and use.

Answer (score 1):

`myMaximumBy` can be simplified using [`foldr1`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Prelude.html#v:foldr1).  The list argument can then be made implicit.

```
myMaximumBy :: (a -> a -> Ordering) -> [a] -> a
myMaximumBy f = foldr1 (\a b -> if f a b == GT then a else b)
```